# Update count when i deselected cell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I have counter which show number of selected cell, i wanna update this number when i deselected cell, this my code:

CustomTableViewCell:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if(selected) {
            self.selectionStyle = .none
            self.shadowView.isHidden = false
            self.checkboxBtn.isHidden = false
        } else {
            self.shadowView.isHidden = true
            self.checkboxBtn.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

ViewController with tableview(this func show number selected cell):

```
 func updateCount() {
        if let list = usersTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows as? [IndexPath] {
            usersNumber.text = String(list.count)
        }
    }
```

UITableViewDelegate:

```
extension UsersController: UITableViewDelegate {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if let cell = self.usersTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? UsersTableViewCell {
                cell.checkboxBtn.isHidden = false
                cell.shadowView.isHidden = false
                cell.selectionStyle = .none
                updateCount()
            }
        }
    }
```

if i deselected cell, number on counter remains the same.

Comment: "if i deselected cell, number on counter remains the same." When this happens, `didSelectRowAt` isn't called, so `updateCount()` isn't called. You need to implement also the delegate method `tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt)`

Comment: i do this on 3 screen) i debug and delegate workning.

Comment: You implemented `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` but there is also `tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:)`: "DEselect vs select"

Comment: damn, its worked i little inattentive and don't see "De", need Iittle rest) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use delegate method tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt):

```
extension UsersController: UITableViewDelegate {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                updateCount()
          
        }
    }
```